# material2 select in flexible box

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I have a container with an arbitrary width and inside I use flexbox, to have:

1. A material2 select box, that should use up all given space automatically
2. Another container with a fixed width next to it, that should always be visible and have a fixed with of 140px:

> ```
>   <div style="display: flex; display: -webkit-flex; width: 300px;">
>     <div style="flex-grow: 1;">
>       <mat-form-field style="width:100%">
>         <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="food">
>           <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
>             {{food.viewValue}}
>           </mat-option>
>         </mat-select>
>       </mat-form-field>
>     </div>
>     <div style="flex-basis: 140px; flex-grow: 0; background-color: #f00;">
>
>     </div>
>   </div>
> ```

Unfortunately the width:100%, covers the whole flex container and therefore hides the static one.

In my plunker you can see the red area as my static element:

https://plnkr.co/edit/E1BE26Zd8L5D3yc6SPPw?p=preview

The red area should be always 140px wide, but in the example it can only take up 100px, because the mat-form-field already needs 200px (this is the default value). However, if I change the 200px width to 100% like in my example, the container covers *everything*.

How can I archive a 140px wide static element with a flexible select drop down next to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `flex-basis: 0` to the styles of the `div` containing the `mat-form-field`. This will work with your `width: 100%` modification.

Comment: Awesome!!! That really worked. Thank you very much! But why did it work? Is there any documentation about width of 100% elements in a flex-basis: 0 container?